# T : U → V and S : V → W are linear transformations between finite-dimensional vector spaces. Show that dim(im(ST)) ≤ min(dim(im(S)), dim(im(T)))

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I understand that I have to show that the dim(Im(ST)) is less than both the dim(Im(S)) and dim(im(T)). But I don't know how to do that.

I know that to show Im(ST) ≤ Im(S). I have to show that Im(ST) is a subspace of Im(S). I don't how to show that Im(ST) ≤ Im(T)

Comment: Try using the Rank-Nullity Theorem.

Comment: I tried doing that. It does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

As you said it's clear that $Im(ST)$ is a subspace of $Im(S)$ and so $dim(Im(ST))\le dim(Im(S))$.

The other inequality $dim(Im(ST))\le dim(Im(T))$ is also true, first note that $dim(Ker(T))\le dim(Ker(ST))$. Then we get, from this inequality and the rank-nullity theorem $dim(Im(T))=dim(U)-dim(Ker(T))\ge dim(U)-dim(Ker(ST))=dim(Im(ST))$

Comment: The inequality in the last line should be reversed.

Comment: yes sorry, it's right now